# How to capture expression for the STP port type local variable

Tags: python, regex

File contents:

```
Name                        Type  Local Value            Peer Value
-------------               ----  ---------------------- ----------------     
STP Port Type               1     Edge Trunk Port        Edge Trunk Port
STP Port Guard              1     Default                Default
STP MST Simulate PVST       1     Default                Default
Vlan xlt mapping            1     Enabled                Enabled
vPC card type               1     Orion                  Orion
Allowed VLANs               -     913                    915
Local error VLANs           -     -                      -
```

Code:

```
import re
with open('regex2+py.txt','r') as file:
o = file.read()
#print(o)
STP_Port_Type = re.findall("(?:^STP\sPort\sType\s+\d\s+(\w+\s\w+\s\w+)",o)  
print(STP_Port_Type)
```

The output is not coming in Python for the above code for the above regex syntax which is `(?:^STP\sPort\sType\s+\d\s+(\w+\s\w+\s\w+)`.

Comment: Add a closing parenthesis `^STP\sPort\sType\s+\d\s+(\w+\s\w+\s\w+)`

Comment: the table is here https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH4L2.png

Comment: Yes, the data was like this I believe https://regex101.com/r/JqBxcU/1

Comment: Yes the data was like that

Comment: In python while printing the output it is not giving any value

Comment: Can you update the question with the data instead of an image, and add the code that you tried and did not work together with the expected results so it is easier for people to help you.

Comment: You are using an anchor `^`, so use `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` see https://ideone.com/ULG0Th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points here:

- Fix your indentations
- When you read a file into a variable using `.read()` a line start position cannot be matched with a mere `^`, you need to use a `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` flag to make it match those line start positions
- To get a single match, you need `re.search`, not `re.findall`.
- If your `STP_Port_Type` value can have unknown amount of words separated with 1 whitespace, you need to fix the pattern to `(?m)^STP\s+Port\s+Type\s+\d+\s+(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqBxcU/2).

Use

```
import re
with open('regex2+py.txt','r') as file:
    o = file.read()                  # Read the file into a variable
    STP_Port_Type = ""               # Initialize STP_Port_Type with empty string
    m = re.search("(?m)^STP\s+Port\s+Type\s+\d+\s+(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)", o) # Find a match
    if m:                            # If there is a match
        STP_Port_Type = m.group(1)   # Assign Group 1 value to STP_Port_Type
    print(STP_Port_Type)
```

**Regex details**

- `(?m)^` - start of line
- `STP\s+Port\s+Type` - `STP Port Type` with any amount of whitespace chars between the words
- `\s+\d+\s+` - 1+ digits enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\s\w+)*)` - Group 1: 1+ word chars and then 0 or more sequences of a single whitespace and then 1+ word chars.